# Artin's theorem 2.33: subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

Theorem 2.33 in Artin states:

> Let $S$ be a subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}^+$. Either $S$ is the trivial subgroup $\{0\}$, or else it has the form $\mathbb{Z}a$, where $a$ is the smallest positive integer in $S$.

Artin starts by taking a subgroup $S$. Surely it has $0$, the identity in $\mathbb{Z}$. If it doesn't have another element, it's the trivial subgroup. If there's a non-zero element, then either it or its inverse is positive, so by the well-ordering principle, there's a least positive element, call it $a$. The claim is then $S = \mathbb{Z}a$.

This is where I am not totally sure I'm following Artin's reasoning. He proves that $S$ is a *subset* of $\mathbb{Z}a$ and that $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}a$. I agree tht it boils down to equality of sets, but we're really interested in proving that $S$ is a *subgroup* of $\mathbb{Z}a$ and $\mathbb{Z}a$ is a *subgroup* of $S$, correct? I assume that the same general logic of establishing subgroups in both directions establishes equality of groups, though more precisely, we're establishing equality of the underlying sets, and if the binary operation is the same -- it is; it's addition in $\mathbb{Z}$ -- then they are the same groups.

He also never proves that $\mathbb{Z}a$ for any $a$ is a subgroup. This is a rather easy verification, but especially if we're proving equality of $\mathbb{Z}a$ with a group $S$, we should establish that we can actually compare these algebraic structures.

Am I off-base here?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? I agree that you need to show that $\mathbb{Z}a$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If you prove equality of sets, and prove that $\mathbb{Z}a$ is a (sub) group, then you are done. So agreed that you must show the latter, but it is rather clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to prove that $S \subseteq a\mathbb{Z}$ and $a\mathbb{Z} \subseteq S$ to show that the two are equal as sets. You do not need to show that they are subgroups of each other, because you are just trying to prove that the set $S$ is literally the set $a\mathbb{Z}.$ Doing anything more is extraneous.

Comment: Is it not also true that they are subgroups of each other? My understanding is that a subgroup is just a subset that admits a group structure. Since both $S$ and $a\mathbb{Z}$ are groups, they should be subgroups of each other.

Comment: @JeremyS They are subgroups of each other, yes, but you don't need to prove that--you just need to prove they are subsets of each other to show the theorem.

Comment: @JeremyS So your comment about verifying that $a\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup is unneeded. If Artin wanted to prove "each $a\mathbb{Z}$ was a subgroup, then you'd need to check this. But Artin wants to prove that each subgroup is of this form. In particular, a statement like "each subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $a\mathbb{Z}$ or $\{1\},$ that would still be correct even though $\{1\}$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: Oh, understood. We could then say, though, that if $S = a\mathbb{Z}$, then $a\mathbb{Z}$ has to be a subgroup -- $S$ is one, by assumption.

Comment: @JeremyS That proof only shows that $a\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup *if* $a$ is the smallest positive element of some subgroup $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, though. So be careful concluding too fast.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you very much for the help.